# How did an objectively answerable question such as this one get closed?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions, close-reasons

A question such as [this](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8875/if-homosexuality-is-a-sin-why-isnt-abstinence) seems to be objectively verifiable via the Bible, so I see no reason for it to have been closed based on the claim that it's "not constructive". It is based solely on the belief that homosexuality is a sin, and if it says that it is a sin in the Bible, then the answer is yes. If not, the answer is no. It's a closed ended, yes or no question. That being said, what is the problem with this question? Is it because it's a "why" question? Where does the problem lie with this question, which simply highlights a contradiction/ambiguity in Christian teaching and seeks to rectify it?

Another issue is that it seems that if it had simply been worded differently, it would have been acceptable. For example, if it were worded, "Given that homosexuality is a sin because it impedes procreation, why is abstinence not a sin as well?", there would be less room for debate and discussion, which is good. But the question would still be the same. So can a question be closed simply on the grounds of its wording? I would simply like some pointers, as two of my questions were voted down, and I really would not like to look at this community in a negative light, and I do want to continue here. So please, any tips on what was done wrong in the question I mentioned above?

Answer (score 6):

"Is X a sin?" questions are usually problematic. They are usually unanswerable unless you address your question at a particular Christian tradition and interpretation framework.

Question wording does matter. A question that *could* be acceptable if was worded differently should expect to be closed until it *is* worded differently. Once it had been edited into shape, the community can vote to re-open it (with less votes than it took to close it).

Answer (score 4):

For one, one of your primary assumptions of the question is not a consistent interpretation of how Christianity views this subject. This shows a lack of research effort on your part in asking the question.

The fact of the matter is that

- Christianity does not universally condemn homosexuality as a sin - various groups view this practice differently, assuming we all do the same thing shows a serious lack of understanding of how vastly different christian denominations and doctrinal positions are.
- Those that do condemn homosexuality as a sin do it for a variety of reasons. Again, you're showing a lack of research here.

Finally, your question was asked in such a way (along with your other question) that does not seek to actually educate yourself on the views of Christians, but instead is seeking to stir up trouble and dissension on this site.

So we have a false premise, a lack of research and a combative question style. That's a closed question to me.

Comment: What is a "combative style"? What constitutes a combative style (specifically) and it what way did you get the impression that there was an attempt to stir up trouble (so that I can avoid it in the future)?

Comment: @allycatgirl you're asking about a hotbutton issue without doing research, how is that not combative?

Comment: Asking a question on the views of Christians seems like an attempt to educate one's self on the views of Christians to me. It is said views that will come as answers to my questions, and therefore soliciting such answers (i.e. asking) seems to be an attempt to gain an understanding of Christian views to me. Combative seems very subjective and it's an interesting way to look at it that would be nice for you to expound on.

Comment: @allycatgirl again, your asking about probably the #1 or #2 debated issue in Christianity today (gender/sex issues are huge issues at large denominational meetings on a yearly(or more regular basis)). With no prior research and using a false premise. I can't help but see that as looking for a fight. If you did not mean it that way I'm sorry, but that's the way it looks.

Answer (score 3):

[*Caleb's response*](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1230/30) is a clear one, and [*wax eagle's response*](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1229/30) emphasizes the importance of completing preliminary research before asking a question.

As far as why some have interpreted the tone as combative, here's a few explanations of what, specifically, they might be referring to. Quotes are from the original post.

- > "But [you] notice a few things wrong with that claim."

  It might seem trivial, but the way that sentence is worded suggests that the speaker is an authoritative judge of what is an is not a relevant claim. Many people have a tendency to get offended when they're told that their beliefs are just plain "wrong." "It seems to [you] that..." would be one different way of wording that, followed perhaps by a concession that you, yourself could be wrong.
- > "Assuming that homosexuality is a sin..."

  Although the sentence structure is grammatical, use of the word "assuming" in reference to what many Christians consider a plain Biblical fact can tend to encourage emotionalism in some.
- Talking about things that would "make people laugh."

  Again, the phrasing of the question does not directly suggest an intent to insult, but, given the highly emotionally charged nature of the topic, it would probably be best to avoid references to ridicule, of any sort.
- Also, a lack of brevity in any question can sometimes make it seem like the asker is trying to prove a point, rather than find an answer.

For some guidelines on how to ask questions on C.SE, see the [*faq*](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/faq). And as far as what kind of preliminary research is useful in asking a question, spending a few minutes reading the results of a Google search often seems to suffice for many. Several people consult Wikipedia, and some use bible commentaries and other research tools available online.

Research on your question, for example, would have quickly led you to a statement in 1 Corinthians 7 that Paul himself was abstinent, and single -- and straight, for that matter.

Cheers.

Comment: -1. "Assuming that homosexuality is a sin..." is perfect: it's a way of scoping the question. The problem with this question is that it wasn't scoped *enough*.